error: request for member 'write' in 'sg90', which is of non-class type 'int' sg90.write(180);
I was trying something for my first project working with Arduino about an automatic trash that open when a hand get close to her. While I was coding, I got an error.
Here is the code:
#include <Servo.h> //librarie de servo moteur

int echo = 7;
int trig = 6;
int sg90 = 8;
int distance;
int duration;

void setup() {
  pinMode(trig, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echo, INPUT);
  sg90.attach(8);

}

void loop() { 
  digitalWrite(trig, LOW);
  delay(2);
  digitalWrite(trig, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trig, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echo, HIGH);
  distance = duration/58.2;

  if(distance<30){
    sg90.write( LOW);
    delay(4500);
    Serial.print(distance);
  }
  else {
    sg90.write(180);
    delay(50);
  }
}

The error said:
error: request for member 'write' in 'sg90', which is of non-class type 'int'
   sg90.write(180);

PS: I am a beginner in coding.

int sg90 = 8; - what in the error message don't you understand?

evrything i a, a nood in coding

also how can i fix it

If you are a newbie in coding, we should start at the beginning - why did you write the line sg90.write(180);? What do you expect it to do?

To be honest i was u sing a code of another person and since my level is too low i was just writing what he wrote so i don't really have any clue of i wrote i did got some basics but that's all

You don't want to copy an alien code blindly. Perhaps you wanted
#include <Servo.h>

enum Pin {
  echo = 7,
  trig = 6,
  sg90 = 8,
};

int distance;
int duration;

Servo sg90;

void setup() {
  pinMode(Pin::trig, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Pin::echo, INPUT);
  sg90.attach(Pin::sg90);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(Pin::trig, LOW);
  delay(2);
  digitalWrite(Pin::trig, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(Pin::trig, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(Pin::echo, HIGH);
  distance = duration / 58.2;

  if (distance < 30) {
    sg90.write(LOW);
    delay(4500);
    Serial.print(distance);
  } else {
    sg90.write(180);
    delay(50);
  }
}

The used manual: Interfacing SG90 Servo with Arduino: A Beginner’s Guide.
